# What is the best way to reject duplicates in a sorted doubly linked list

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, duplicates, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to make a sorted doubly linked list that doesn't insert duplicates, but I am having trouble finding a way to do this. I looked at posts on how to remove duplicates, but no posts on preventing duplicate insertions.

Here is the code I have to insert and sort without rejecting duplicates. The parameter, dataIn takes values from a predefined Student object list in main (Student s = {{gpa, name}, ..., {gpa, name}}:

```
void StudentList::insertNode(Student dataIn)
{
    ListNode *newNode; // A new node pointer
    ListNode *pCur; // To traverse the list
    // Allocate a new node and store num there.
    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->stu = dataIn;
    newNode->forw = NULL;
    newNode->back = NULL;
    
    //Check if there is node in list
    if(head ->forw == NULL && head->back == NULL){
        head->forw = newNode;
        newNode->back = head;
        newNode->forw = head;
        head->back = newNode;
    }
    else{
        // Initialize pointers
        pCur = head->forw;
        // Find location: skip all nodes whose name is less than dataIn's name
        while (pCur != head && pCur->stu.name < dataIn.name)
        {
            pCur = pCur->forw;
        }
        // Insert the new node between pPre and pCur
        ListNode *pPre = pCur->back; // The previous node
        newNode->back = pPre;
        newNode->forw = pCur;
        pCur->back = newNode;
        pPre->forw = newNode;
    }
    // Update the counter
    count++;
}
```

Does anyone know a way for rejecting duplicates without deleting? Thanks everyone!

Comment: When you try something and it doesn't work, please don't then ask a question "what is the best way to XYZ".  Instead, ask a question about the actual problem.  If there's a better way, someone might helpfully point that out at the same time as identifying your problem.

Comment: Step 1 is to write a `bool StudentList::contains(const Student & s) const` method that returns true iff there is already a `Student` equal to `s` in the list.  Step two is to add `if (contains(dataIn)) return;` to the top of your `insert()` method.

Comment: At the end of `while (pCur != head && pCur->stu.name < dataIn.name)` loop, there are three possibilities. 1) `pCur == head` - you've come full circle, `dataIn.name` is smaller than all other names; 2) `pCur->stu.name > dataIn.name` - you've found a place where to insert the new name; 3) `pCur->stu.name == dataIn.name` - there already exist a node with the same name, `dataIn` is a duplicate and should be rejected. You do not need any additional data structures.

Comment: When you "_Check if there is node in list_" you do `if(head ->forw == NULL) ...` but isn't `head == NULL` before you've inserted the first node? If it is, you can't do `head->forw` or `head->back`.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect if `pCur->stu.name == dataIn.name` after the `while` loop in your first code sample?

Comment: @paddy Sorry about that, I updated the question!

Comment: @JaMiT I don't want to insert if `code`pCur->stu.name == dataIn.name`code`, the detection should be inside the while loop since that is where the inserting is taking place.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The list is predefined in main. Sorry for not mentioning that. I updated the post :D

Comment: "that is where the inserting is taking place" — not quite, the insertion occurs after the while loop when you update the `back` and `forw` pointers. But it doesn't matter either way: the while loop finds the place the node should be inserted, so can you just check at that moment (after updating pCur, or after the while loop) whether you have found an equal node.

Comment: @drewster In `main`? `head` should be `private` so I don't see what `main` has to do with it. Also, I don't see the update of the question.

Comment: @drewster Equivalent to my earlier comment: *"Are you asking how to detect if `pCur->stu.name == dataIn.name` just before the comment `// Insert the new node between pPre and pCur`, which happens to be just after the `while` loop?"* You did put that comment at the place where the insertion takes place, right?

Comment: @JaMiT Yea, I goofed and all it required was this line after the while loop If(pCur->stu.name == dataIn.name){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to reject duplicates in a sorted doubly linked list?

I suggest delaying the creation of the new `ListNode` until you know that the new node isn't a duplicate.

Assuming that the `ListNode` looks like this

```
struct ListNode {        
    Student stu;
    ListNode *back;
    ListNode *forw;
};
```

and that you have a `head` and `tail` `ListNode*` that is set to `nullptr` when the `StudentList` is empty, then the `insertNode` function could look like this:

```
bool StudentList::insertNode(const Student& dataIn) { // return true if node is inserted
    ListNode* prev = nullptr;
    ListNode* pCur = head;

    // search for a good insertion spot
    for(; pCur; prev = pCur, pCur = pCur->forw) {
        if(dataIn.name == pCur->stu.name) return false; // equal, reject
        if(dataIn.name < pCur->stu.name) break;         // found a good spot before pCur
    }

    // delayed creation until here:
    ListNode* newNode = new ListNode{dataIn, prev, pCur};

    // linking        
    if(prev) prev->forw = newNode;
    else head = newNode;
    
    if(pCur) pCur->back = newNode;
    else tail = newNode; // comment this line out if you don't have a "tail"

    ++count;

    return true; // node inserted
}
```

Comment: This is the simple solution I was looking for. Thanks for the help!